# How to create a VertexId in Apache Spark GraphX using a Long data type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm trying to create a Graph using some Google Web Graph data which can be found here:

https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Google.html

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD



val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://n018-data.hursley.ibm.com/user/romeo/web-Google.txt")
val arrayForm = textFile.filter(_.charAt(0)!='#').map(_.split("\\s+")).cache()
val nodes = arrayForm.flatMap(array => array).distinct().map(_.toLong)
val edges = arrayForm.map(line => Edge(line(0).toLong,line(1).toLong))

val graph = Graph(nodes,edges)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Long]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, ?)]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val graph = Graph(nodes,edges)
```

So how can I create a VertexId object? For my understanding it should be sufficient to pass a Long.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

romeo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly. If you take a look at the signature of the `apply` method of the `Graph` object you'll see something like this (for a full signature see [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph$)):

```
apply[VD, ED](
    vertices: RDD[(VertexId, VD)], edges: RDD[Edge[ED]], defaultVertexAttr: VD)
```

As you can read in a description:

> Construct a graph from a collection of vertices and edges **with attributes**.

Because of that you cannot simply pass `RDD[Long]` as a `vertices` argument ( `RDD[Edge[Nothing]]` as `edges` won't work either).

```
import scala.{Option, None}

val nodes: RDD[(VertexId, Option[String])] = arrayForm.
    flatMap(array => array).
    map((_.toLong, None))

val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] = arrayForm.
    map(line => Edge(line(0).toLong, line(1).toLong, ""))
```

Note that:

> Duplicate vertices are picked arbitrarily

so `.distinct()` on `nodes` is obsolete in this case.

If you want to create a `Graph` without attributes you can use `Graph.fromEdgeTuples`.

Comment: Hi, following back to the question in the title, is there no way to create a vertex object on the fly like you can with edges? For example val test = Edge(1, 1, 1) . I tried val test = Vertex(1, 1) and haven't been able to find any constructor online.

Comment: @mt88 There is no need for that. `Vertex` is just a `Tuple2[VertexId, T]` where `VertexId` is an alias for `Long`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message said that `nodes` must be type of `RDD[(Long, anything else)]`. The first element in tuple is vertexId and the second element could anything, for example, String with node description. Try to simply repeat vertexId:

```
val nodes = arrayForm
             .flatMap(array => array)
             .distinct()
             .map(x =>(x.toLong, x.toLong))
```